# Displays an error as "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Tags: php, xml

I tried a xml document in localhost, but it shows error as "**XML Parsing Error: not well-formed**
Location: http://localhost/xml/user.php
,  Line Number 4, Column 906:

I searched for any errors in the structure of the xml file, such as a missing end-tags. but i couldn't find.

But when I ran this xml file (without removing any element - original xml file) in the browser without php tags. it works well and shows the tree structure in the browser.

my codes are as follows;

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
echo "<xs:schema
xmlns='http://www.google.com'
xmlns:xs='http://www.google.com'
xs:schemaLocation='http://www.google.com'>";
echo "    <xs:user>";
echo "        <xs:element1 name='username'>";
echo "            <xs:simpleType>";
echo "                <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>";
echo "                  <xs:minLength value='5'/>";
echo "                  <xs:maxLength value='12'/>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='[a-zA-Z0-9]'/>";
echo "                  <xs:whiteSpace value='collapse'/>";
echo "              </xs:restriction>";
echo "            </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element1>";
echo "      <xs:element2 name='password'>";
echo "          <xs:simpleType>";
echo "              <xs:restrictions base='xs:string'>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='[a-zA-Z0-9]'/>";
echo "                  <xs:minLength value='8'/>";
echo "              </xs:restrictions>";
echo "          </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element2>";
echo "      <xs:element3 name='fullname' type='xs:string'/>";   
echo "      <xs:element4 name='initials'>";
echo "          <xs:simpleType>";
echo "              <xs:restrictions base='xs:string'>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'/>";
echo "                  <xs:whiteSpace value='collapse'/>";
echo "              </xs:restrictions>";
echo "          </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element4>";
echo "      <xs:element5 name='gender'>";
echo "          <xs:simpleType>";
echo "              <xs:restrictions base='xs:string>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='male|female'/>";
echo "              </xs:restrictions>";
echo "          </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element5>";            
echo "  </xs:user>";
echo "</xs:schema>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed a single quote here `<xs:restrictions base='xs:string'>` and also remove line breaks from line number 4

Here is your `xml`

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
echo '<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.google.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.google.com" xs:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com">';
echo "    <xs:user>";
echo "        <xs:element1 name='username'>";
echo "            <xs:simpleType>";
echo "                <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>";
echo "                  <xs:minLength value='5'/>";
echo "                  <xs:maxLength value='12'/>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='[a-zA-Z0-9]'/>";
echo "                  <xs:whiteSpace value='collapse'/>";
echo "              </xs:restriction>";
echo "            </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element1>";
echo "      <xs:element2 name='password'>";
echo "          <xs:simpleType>";
echo "              <xs:restrictions base='xs:string'>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='[a-zA-Z0-9]'/>";
echo "                  <xs:minLength value='8'/>";
echo "              </xs:restrictions>";
echo "          </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element2>";
echo "      <xs:element3 name='fullname' type='xs:string'/>";   
echo "      <xs:element4 name='initials'>";
echo "          <xs:simpleType>";
echo "              <xs:restrictions base='xs:string'>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'/>";
echo "                  <xs:whiteSpace value='collapse'/>";
echo "              </xs:restrictions>";
echo "          </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element4>";
echo "      <xs:element5 name='gender'>";
echo "          <xs:simpleType>";
echo "              <xs:restrictions base='xs:string'>";
echo "                  <xs:pattern value='male|female'/>";
echo "              </xs:restrictions>";
echo "          </xs:simpleType>";
echo "      </xs:element5>";            
echo "  </xs:user>";
echo "</xs:schema>";
?>
```